# How to deal with a stateful widget as a child for grid.tile

Tags: gridview, flutter, statefulwidget

I am new to flutter. and I am trying to make an x o game. I am still on the very first steps of the app. I am using gridview.count to make the layout of the game. The problem is the properties of the stateful widget(choice, onTap()) is not defined in the gridview tile. This is my code

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Tic Tac Toe')),
        body: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
          mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
          children: List<Widget>.generate(
            9,
            (int index) {return new GridTile(
             child:GridCell(

                    choice: _choice,
                    onTap: ()=>onTap(context),
                  ),
                );
            })))
```

and the class is:

```
class GridCellState extends State<TicTacToe> {
  final String choice;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
   GridCellState({Key key, this.choice, this.onTap}) : 
  super(key: key);
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return GestureDetector(
     onTap:onTap,
     child:Container(
       child: Text(choice),
       height:20.0,
       color:Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
     ),
   );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I created same tic-tac-toe using row-column-view(instead of GridView by mistake) https://github.com/dineshba/tictactoe_flutter/tree/master/lib.  But it might help you as your problem is mostly with `onTap` and `choice`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are wiring up the constructor in a wrong way, you do not construct the object from the `State` object, that is the job of the `StatefulWidget` is to construct the `State` object. You construct an instance of a `StatefulWidget` called `GridCell` so `GridCell` needs to have the fields and the constructor moved to it.

In short ,you need to move the `GridCellState` fields and constructor up to the `StatefulWidget` itself like this:

```
class GridCell extends StatefulWidget {
  final String choice;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  GridCell({Key key, this.choice, this.onTap}) : 
  super(key: key);

  @override
  GridCellState createState() {
    return new GridCellState();
  }
}
```

and then use `widget.fieldName` from inside the `State` object to access any field in the `StatefulWidget` object, see I use `widget.onTap` and `widget.choice` to get fields data from my `StatefulWidget` above.

```
class GridCellState extends State<GridCell> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return GestureDetector(
     onTap:widget.onTap,
     child:Container(
       child: Text(widget.choice),
       height:20.0,
       color:Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
     ),
   );
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can just convert your `GridCell` to a `SatelessWidget` instead, both approaches will solve your issue so it depends whether you need to keep the `StatefulWidget` or not.